# Good counter to go to next and previous picture in array in iPhone view?

Tags: ios, arrays, counter

In a view that will display images (in an array) and have a next and previous buttons that are connected to respective next and previous methods.

How do I create a counter to use for the objectAtIndex:counter?

The requirements for the navigation of the pictures in the array are:

- Click next -> next picture
- Click previous ->Previous picture
- Click next and its the last picture -> go to first picture
- Click previous and its the first picture -> go to last picture
- No pictures (first time you run and before you create) -> do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily 
You need to create a global varible(count) for that class and then do it.

```
-(IBAction)previousImage:(id)sender
{
    if(count==0)
    {
        count=array.count-1;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[array objectAtIndex:count]];

    }
    else
    {
        count--;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[array objectAtIndex:count]];
    }
}
-(IBAction)nextImage:(id)sender
{
    if(count==array.count-1)
   {
        count=0;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[array objectAtIndex:count]];
  } 
    else
    {
        count++;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[array objectAtIndex:count]];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need "total" variable, you can use `count` property of array.

Comment: You shouldn't really need to bother with a total variable.  You can just use the array's count method to get its size.  Minor change, but it makes the code more reliable if you were to add/remove an image from the array.  You wouldn't have to update the total variable.  Edit:  Marcus ninja'd me

Comment: +1 Nice job. OP might want to turn these into functions that return a `UIImage` or `nil`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams yes it will be more easy but now i don't have enough time its up to questioner....

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try. How come I get the warning:  Comparison between pointer and integer ('NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') and 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *')) 
when comparing my static NSUInteger counter in -> 
 if (counter==total) {}   ?? 

total is: NSInteger *total = ...

Comment: Don't do NSInteger *total.  You don't need a pointer.  NSInteger total = ... will do the job and will be comparable to an unsigned int.

Comment: Ah ok, this is actually the rootCause to my issue with the counter because I used a *tempCounter = count to avoid warning and I guess they then relate to eachother and the values change twice or not at all etc. Thanks it works great!

Answer (score 0):

here total is number of images.

```
-(IBAction)previous:(id)sender{
    if(count==0)
        count=total-1;
    else
        count--;
}
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender{
    if(count==total-1)
        count=0;
    else
        count++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemented code (I use a singelton and coreData for saving the images) based on the answer and comments above:

```
static NSUInteger count;
- (IBAction)onNext{


DataControllerSingleton *singletonData= [DataControllerSingleton singleDataController];
NSInteger total = [singletonData countOfList];

self.cares = [singletonData allObjects];

if(count == total-1)
{
    count=0;

    NSObject *ob = [cares objectAtIndex:count];
    self.backgroundImage.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[ob          
    valueForKey:@"imageData"]];
}
else
{
    count++;
    NSObject *ob = [cares objectAtIndex:count];
    self.backgroundImage.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[ob 
    valueForKey:@"imageData"]];
}

}




 - (IBAction)onPrevious{

DataControllerSingleton *singletonData= [DataControllerSingleton singleDataController];

NSInteger total = [singletonData countOfList];
self.cares = [singletonData allObjects];

if(count==0)
{
    count=total-1;
    NSObject *ob = [cares objectAtIndex:count];
    self.backgroundImage.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[ob    
    valueForKey:@"imageData"]];

}
else
{
    count--;
    NSObject *ob = [cares objectAtIndex:count];
    self.backgroundImage.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[ob     
   valueForKey:@"imageData"]];
}

}
```